# Callback functionality in jQuery components

Tags: jquery

I am going through jQuery tutorials, and I got a query with jQuery callback functions. The below is a very good example of jQuery callback function.

```
$("p").hide(1000,function(){
    alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
});
```

It works fine, but how can we know that to what function does this callback functionality is available?

For example, how can we apply this callback functionality to an on-click button?

Answer (score 1):

You should first know the concept of **callback function**. A callback function is a function which would be passed to another function, to be executed usually at a later time. (I know this definition is not 100% right. Just for educational purposes).

For example, you tell the jQuery to validate a form for you. What if it's valid? What then? What if it's invalid?

You can consider this code:

```
$('form').validate(validFormAction, invalidForm);
```

This in plain English is saying:

Please validate the form. If the form is valid, then please run **validFormAction** function. If it's not valid, then run the **invalidForm** function.

Thus, you usually know by instinct and intuitively which functions need callback. For example, `animate` function accepts a callback. It's so, because `animate` function takes a little **time** and you can specify another function (a callback function) to be called at its end.

As other have said, you can refer to jQuery documents too, to see which get a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the API of the functions to check whether a callback is supported. http://api.jquery.com/
You can apply the callback functionality to on click as below

```
$("p").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph is clicked");
});
```

Comment: This is not a callback function @sewdil.